# PHP - Use variable in mysqli string result

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi the Stack community, 
I'm actually facing a situation, so let met explain :

On my CRM I'd write in text area named "Script" :
**"Hi, I'm $username from company.How can I help you ?"**
This is saved into the mysql database.
[The text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEJ7E.png)

On the front end, the user login into his account his name is added to $username.
When I try `<?php echo $username; ?>` I get : "Michael".

[Front end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yOdW.png)

But when I echo the "Script" from the database, the output is the same :
 **"Hi, I'm $username from company. How can I help you ?"**

How can I with PHP change **$username** of the sentence by the name of the variable.

Thanks :)

Comment: This question is unclear, can you clarify what you expected and try to rephrase your question to something specific. You should also post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str_replace()` to replace the variable.

```
$string_from_db = 'Hi, I\'m $username from company. How can I help you ?';
echo str_replace('$username', $username, $string_from_db);
```

Output:

```
Hi, I'm Michael from company. How can I help you ?
```

If you have multiple different values you may want to change, you could supply arrays to `str_replace()`.

```
$string_from_db = 'Hi, I\'m $username from company. How can I help you ?';

$replacements = [
    'from' => [
        '$username',
        '$other_var'
    ],
    'to' => [
        $username,
        $other_var
    ]
];

echo str_replace($replacements['from'], $replacements['to'], $string_from_db);
```

Comment: Much better than mine. Fridays hehe, I should get some sleep. Upvoted.

Comment: Totally agree, going to delete that.

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't taught of replacing... All my mind was in something with eval().... Thanks very much ;)

Comment: @Michael No problem, glad I could help :)